# Android Client-Server through NDK

Tags: android, apache, tomcat, android-ndk

I want to communicate with Apache Tomcat server using android ndk(native code).
Is it possible to communiate , Is there any other alternative to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use ndk when there are already plenty of good utils available?  You can check out this link for some basics http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/

Comment: @MikeIsrael : It is just a web page fetching example

Comment: You are extremely unclear on what you need to do, do you need tcp, udp connections, what? either way a simple search in google will produce native libraries for what you want.

Comment: @MikeIsrael : I want to send some data from android ndk(native code) to the web server.

Comment: but why from ndk why aren't you using the android sdk, there are a ton of libraries already ready?

Comment: @MikeIsrael : My use case is something like that only.

Comment: Standard posix socket code should work just fine for the connection creation. Over that, you can write your own application layer communication code, or better still, use one of the numerous libraries that implement HTTP or SOAP to do your communication.

Comment: @Samveen : Well thanks for your reply. Just a query will these posix sockets work on android ndk. I am not sure about it.Android has got completely different api set for c and c++. :(

Answer (score 2):

Standard POSIX socket code can be used for networking in Android. The socket system call api for android can be found at https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT (this is a clone of the official android C library repo). This should take care of your network layer requirements. As for the code, the code for a simple network client can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Client. However, this is only in the case you want to write up your own application layer protocol( I assume HTTP) code. It is better to use an HTTP client library instead,.

As for an HTTP client library, you could use libcurl or any similar library for communication. A good list of available libraries on the libcurl site at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html.

Note: You will most probably not get any compiled library. You'll need to compile and add the library into your application before you compile your code, and the library will need to be a part of the install package as well.

Comment: Thanks samveen for the help. Just one more query ,  can I use http library on client side which is in c as the links above are pointing. And Server running in Java. Do I need to write my own handshaking protocols to communicate.

Comment: Chetan, my understanding is that, as you're using the tomcat server, you'll communicate using HTTP. What data you send over HTTP is completely up to you. That said, as the communication protocol is HTTP, it doesn't matter what language the server is written in as compared to the client(both sides understand the protocol and communicate over the network)